# How to post premitive types using Postman using Json?

Tags: post, postman

I have simple API developed using ASP.NET core

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class WorkunitController : Controller
{
    private IRepository _repository = null;
    public WorkunitController(IRepository repositoty)
    {
        _repository = repositoty;
    }       

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task SetTransformed([FromBody]long id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _repository.SetTransformed(id);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in POSTMAN I did the following

- Set URL
- Add headers

  - "Content-Type" as "application/json"
- Set Body

  {
        "id":51437665009
     }

When I click on Send, I see the request comes to the server but ModelState.IsValid is `false` and there is exception in ModelState

> - Exception   {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>     'System.Int64' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g.
>     string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly. To fix this
>     error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string,
>     number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type so that it is a
>     normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a
>     collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized
>     from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type
>     to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'id', line 2,
>     position 17.    at
>     Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader
>     reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>     JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>     Object existingValue)    at
>     Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>     reader, Type objectType, Boolean
>     checkAdditionalContent)}  System.Exception
>     {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException}

I have also tried sending `id` as

```
   { \"id\":\"51437665009\"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use json as data type, you need to create a custom class for binding

```
public class PostModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task SetTransformed([FromBody]PostModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _repository.SetTransformed(id);
    }
}
```